# Include same libraries into 2 cpp files in the same project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have been trying with not much success to call a function which uses the same library includes as the function in my main.cpp.
To be more specific:

Main.cpp

```
#include "dlib\all\source.cpp"
#include Function.h
   ...
```

Function.cpp

```
#include "dlib\all\source.cpp"
   ...
```

This produces the error lnk1169 one or more defined symbols found

If i just define the #include in the Function.h and include the Function.h inside my Main cpp the same error appears. 
So how can someone have in the same project in visual studio 2012 two cpp files that both require the same includes?

EDIT:
Ignorance can be really bad at times. What it needed to be done was the source.cpp file to be added to the project not to be included.

Comment: Why are you including a .cpp file? Why not the header .h?

Comment: Hello. Please check my comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably include a header instead of a cpp source file. 
Something like
    #include "dlib\all\source.h"

iol answer seems the right thing to do :

> Directly from the site:dlib.net/compile.html. All you need to do is
>   create an empty console project. Then add dlib/all/source.cpp to it
>   and add the folder containing the dlib folder to the #include search
>   path. Then you can compile any example program by adding it to your
>   project

Comment: in the slib library there is not something like that cause source.cpp contains includes .h files.

Comment: I do not still think this is the way to do it cf http://dlib.net/object_detector_advanced_ex.cpp.html. Maybe you could provide us more informations such as compile line command and code.

Comment: Directly from the site:http://dlib.net/compile.html. All you need to do is create an empty console project. Then add dlib/all/source.cpp to it and add the folder containing the dlib folder to the #include search path. Then you can compile any example program by adding it to your project